# daisychaining select_related functions?

Tags: django

I have the below which joins the notifications model to the task model and returns all fields - it works!

```
notificationsx = notifications.objects.filter(orgid__in=t).select_related('task').all()
```

But, I also need to join the task model to the projects model - so I have all task, notifications and project fields in one output.I tried the below but it didn't work daisy chaining all the things together.

Can anyone help me please?

```
notificationsx = notifications.objects.filter(orgid__in=t).select_related('task').all().select_related('project').all().order_by('-epoch')[:15]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put *all* of them in a single [**`.select_related(…)`** clause <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related):

```
notificationsx = (
    notifications.objects.filter(orgid__in=t)
    .select_related('task', 'project')
    .order_by('-epoch')[:15]
)
```

Comment: Well, that was easy :) thanks so much!